# Permissions issue on backup script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[My spreadsheet for containing the archived information](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/146WU8RghfFqlCpCSX7n6kBAKOyxcpVKt14yhVfvYz-g/edit?usp=sharing)

[Sample of daily sheet that needs archiving](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UCHpSnKd6C_rCxdipf_K0MS-1Bj3Ipqw2U-EOW7OCRE/edit?usp=sharing)

I have the code below that is used to insert a menu button so it can be manually backed up at end of day, see below.
When I copy this daily sheet using a script it keeps all the information but I have to authorise every sheet to run script.

My question is can I make the script run without any authorisation or is there another way to automate the sending of the data from 4 of the 6 sheets to the corresponding sheets on the archive sheet?
As it is a collaboration if I am away or off no-one else can authorise the script.
How would YOU handle this?
Thank you in advance.

```
function onOpen() { // This function adds a custom menu to the spreadsheet (Backup to archive) so you can run the script from there.
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Backup')
    .addItem('Backup','dataBackup')
    .addToUi();
}
function nameOfSpreadsheet() {
  var s=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getName().replace(/(\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}).*/,'$1');
  return s;
}

function dataBackup() {
  var inputSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var archiveSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById('146WU8RghfFqlCpCSX7n6kBAKOyxcpVKt14yhVfvYz-g');
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var sheetNames = ['AM trip', 'PM trip', 'Pool / Beach', 'Night Dive'];
  for (var i = 0; i < sheetNames.length; i++) {   
    var inputSheet = inputSS.getSheetByName(sheetNames[i]);
    var archiveSheet = archiveSS.getSheetByName(sheetNames[i]);
    var date = inputSheet.getRange('A2').getValue(); // Changed to stop inadvertent cell changes, also made text white so not seen.
    var data = inputSheet.getRange('E7:U37').getValues().filter(function(row) { return row[0] !== '' || row[1] !== ''});

    for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
      data[x].splice(0, 0, date);
    }

    var getDate = archiveSheet.getRange(archiveSheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValue();
    var maxRowLength = data.reduce(function(length, row) { return Math.max(length, row.length); }, 0);
    var date = new Date(date); 
    var getDate = new Date(getDate);

    if (getDate.getDate() === "Loading Data...") {
      Utilities.sleep(30000);
    }

    if (getDate.getDate() != date.getDate() || getDate.getMonth() != date.getMonth()) {     
      if (data.length != 0) {
        archiveSheet.insertRowsAfter(archiveSheet.getLastRow(), data.length);
         archiveSheet.getRange(archiveSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, data.length, maxRowLength).setValues(data);
      } else {
        archiveSheet.insertRowsAfter(archiveSheet.getLastRow(), 1);
        archiveSheet.getRange(archiveSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 2).setValues([[date, 'No Data']]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How about you move the backup task to the archive sheet? I would assume you have all Documents in a folder, it could back up everything that hasn't been backed up yet every time it runs in a trigger basis?

Comment: @RobinGertenbach The daily spreadsheet workbook has 6 sheets + 1 hidden but only need the first 4 backed up to the archive sheet.  Did originally have this on the archive sheet but was trying to automate the whole process and this seemed easier as I make 1 workbook for each day of year but can make them months in advance,  but only want the final backup done after the date in the title of the sheet.  Obviously that means up to 365 separate file ids to scan and copy but only 1 per day?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, but you can use `getFiles` using driveapp and `getName()` on each file. Any reason you'd want to avoid that?

Comment: @RobinGertenbach, Can you elaborate please on your last comment from Sep18th, sorry been away for a few days.  Do you mean use the script with your getFiles not in the archive sheet? If so then how would it know which sheet to grab the input from as the sheet is a different one daily?  I would like to automate the whole thing, which is why I went to the input sheet for the script as this is then copied each time I make a copy so less work, however if it needs permission to run each time if I am not the one to push the button then I am back to Square 1!